# Magento - use pretty URL rather than query string params

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using querystring params to load video media in a template file, and the URL looks like this:

`http://mysite.com/?step=5&vid=1`

The way I currently map the URL to the template file is standard way in the CMS, ie, in CMS Pages I add a URL key 'steps' and a route in `/var/www/simplesteps/site/src/app/code/local/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml` that maps to my template `.phtml` file in /template/page/

I would like to use URLs without querystring params, something like:

`http://mysite.com/step5/vid1`, or `http://mysite.com/site/5/vid/1`

Whichever structure does not matter as I will parse the request myself to get the params from inside the template file.

How can I achieve this URL so that I can still get through to the same template file?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Magento, and the standard controller/action path thing, you can achieve this simply :

http://www.mysite.com/module/controller/action/param1/value/param2/value

ex. http://www.mysite.com/company/video/view/step/5/video/1

Then in the controller function, you can retrieve these params as $_GET value with :

$this->getRequest()->getParam('step'); or $this->getRequest()->getParam('video');